# split text and inline comment with regex

Tags: regex

My goal is to parse these two types of text:
`Any#text;more  ; a comment` or `Any#text;more  # a comment` and `Any#text;no comment`

It is an arbitrary line of text with an optional comment. The comment indicator is a `#` or `;` preceded by at least one whitespace.

My approach before was `^(?<value>([^#;])+)(\s*[#;](?<comment>.*))?$` that is a group `value` that accepts everything except the comment indicators followed optionally by the indicator and a group `comment`.

This worked out well until I realized, that I sometimes have the comment indicator chars in the value, too.

I'm trying grouping, pos/neg lookahead/behind in various combinations with the regex101.com verifier and debugger since a hour now and am totally stuck.

The best I could get is `^(?<value>(.+(?=\s#|\s;)))(\s*[#;](?<comment>.*))?$` which splits very good value and comment, but now the comment is somehow mandatory.
Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

ps: using this inside c# and yes, it has to be regex, and no, its no homework ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this refactored regex for the cases you have described:

```java
^(?<value>.+?(?=\s[;#]|$))(?:\s*[#;](?<comment>.*))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTwnth/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?<value>`: Start named capture group `value`

  - `.+?`: Match 1+ of any characters (non-greedy)
  - `(?=\s[;#]|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have a whitespace followed by `#` or `;` OR else **(for lines with no comments)** end of line ahead
- `)`: End capture group `value`
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `\s*[#;]`: Match 0+ whitespaces followed by `#` or `;`
  - `(?<comment>.*)`: named capture group `comment` to match everything till end
- `)?`: End *optional* non-capture group
- `$`: End